# how to define -std=c++11 as default in g++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, derived-class

I'm using some features in my C++ programs that I need `-std=c++11` option set in g++

Is it possible set this option as a default and don't be necessary use this all time I compile it?

Or how to set this in Makefile.

Comment: Set it in `CXXFLAGS`

Comment: Does it have to be exactly C++11 or is a newer standard also accepted?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm using `-std=c++11` to don't get an error on instructions like that:  `x = {0, 4};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you typically set this in a Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

One layer above you can also detect a suitable compiler via `autoconf`, `cmake` or whichever other meta-buildtool you might deploy.

You of course play games as define `g++11` as `g++ -std=c++11` but such set-ups are not portable.

g++-6.* will default to c++14 so at some this switch will be implicit.  But it might take a really long time for all those RHEL and CentOS boxen with g++-4.4.* to disappear.  Those may not even handle your current project...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, upgrade to GCC 6.1:

> The C++ frontend now defaults to C++14 standard instead of C++98

From https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2016-04/msg00244.html

Comment: The question specifically asks about `-std=c++11`, which probably means OP wants C++11, not C++14.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a makefile do this as follows (this is a simple version with no variables).

```
out: source.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 source.cpp -o out
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your build system of choice. Be that `make`, `SCons`, `CMake`, `qmake` or something else, and set the required option.  Should take all of 30 seconds and you're done.

Or, upgrade your compiler to a version that uses C++11 by default.